# C# Mysql no update data

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying create a class in C# for manipulate Mysql data 
I can get datas with my methods but I can't update data, and no return nothing exceptions

I using this line for call my method

`Email1.Text=bdOp.alterContent(Email1.Text, "Email");`

Method 'alterContent':

```
public String alterContent(String valor, String nome)
{
    String query = "update conteudo set conteudo = @valor where nome= @nome ";
```

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor", valor);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);

try
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return "Sucesso.";
}
catch (Exception erro) { return erro.ToString(); }
```

}

This method has return String, because I had using to check exceptions
I don't know why this code no update my data and no return any exceptions

Comment: Commit would work if he were using a `SqlTransaction` object also where is this Declared `cmd` you need to create relevant objects in the Method code block it's a `Debugging nightmare` if you try to use a Global `SqlCommand` Object

Comment: Oh.. so sorry, I haven't talked what class i had use. So.... I'm using... MySqlConnection conn; MySqlCommand cmd; MySqlDataReader reader;

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation last night... it was in MVC, so I had to stop the virtual localhost, and do a clean build. After restarting visual studio... it worked. I wasn't getting any error either.

Also, validate the text in Email.Text, perhaps something there might be triggering a problem.